# ¿Como detecto cuando cancelas un input (Cargar imagen)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buen día, de antemano muchas gracias, Tengo un botón para subir imágenes y ese proceso funciona bien, lo que quiero es saber cuando cancelan el evento de subir imagen con el botón de `cancelar` en vez de darle: `Seleccionar`.
Estoy trabajando sobre **JavaScript** y **ReactJS**

```
<input 
      hidden 
      accept="image/*" 
      multiple = { false }
      type="file"
      alt="Imagen a análisar"
      onChange={(e) => sendImageAction(e.target.files[0])} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

creo que no existe una forma en especifico de saber si seleccionaste algo o no, podrías utilizar el evento onFocus para detectar los eventos clickeados y onChange cuando se haya hecho seleccionado algo.

```
const revisarCarga = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value?.length = 0) {
      //tu logica de lo que debes hacer si no...
    }
  };

  const enCarga = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value?.length > 0) {
      //tu logica de lo que debes hacer si se cargó...
    }
  };

<input
      accept="image/*"
      multiple={false}
      type="file"
      alt="Imagen a análisar"
      onChange={(e) => enCarga(e)}
      onFocus={(e) => revisarCarga (e)}
    />
```

Pruebalo y cualquier cosa deja un comentario.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, pero no me funciono, no detecta cambios con el botón “Canelar”, que tengas excelente día, seguiré buscando solución a mi problema!

Comment: Hay un evento `cancel` que solo funciona en Firefox y está en etapa experimental. Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#browser_compatibility

Comment: Interesante, aunque creo que lo dejaré pendiente porque si lo necesito para todos los exploradores, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.